# rails attribute names camelcase issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, camelcasing

I have legacy Sql Server database and Rails applications. Column names
in database are all in PascalCase `(FirstName, CustomerId...).`

I'm searching for an easy way to use underscore_casing in Ruby and
PascalCasing in database. I would like to write `first_name` in Rails
for FirstName column in database.

camelize and underscore will convert a string to required casing

but I'm looking for something more general like:
`ActiveRecord::Base.camelize_table_column_names = true`

like existing
`ActiveRecord::Base.pluralize_table_names`

Just like translating Ruby in rjs templates to JavaScript cameCase
convention.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe set up aliases for all defined column names?

```
column_names.each do |column_name|
  alias_attribute column_name.underscore, column_name
end
```

You could add that to a concern and include that concern in all relevant models.

Comment: +1, but there might be a slight issue with including the concern, this must happen after `table_name` is set if the table name does not match the class name.

Comment: Good point. Though you can just add that table name bit to the concern too.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a single option that would switch on such behavior. Rails, after all, obeys the [convention over configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions) principle but not all internal conventions are configurable.

On the other hand you should be able to **define [column aliases](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-alias_attribute) for all of your columns**, e.g:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
   alias_attribute :first_name, :FirstName
   # etc...
end
```

This way Rails should transparently "translate" the underscore attributes to CamelCase ones:

```
Customer.where(first_name: "John")
# => SELECT `customers`.* FROM `customers` WHERE `customers`.`FirstName` = 'John'
```